# How to get the value of jQuery generated radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to get the value of radio button which is generated by jQuery. I think there is some problem in call events. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="divOption1"></div>
```

jQuery radio button generates:

```
document.getElementById('divOption1').innerHTML = '<input id="option1" type="radio" value="1"/> '+ questions[currentQuestion]['option1'];
```

Here I call jQuery function to get radio button value:

```
$("#option1").click(function (){
        alert($(this).val());
    })
```

Help me to figure out where is the problem,
and tell me why event are not called when I generate jQuery Html and append to web page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click to bind event with dynamically generated elements. You have to delegate to parent element could be document or any parent element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDLQx/)**

```
$(document).on("click", "#option1", function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: or may be $("#divOption1").on .. instead of $(document)?

Comment: on() didn't work but .live() work perfectly. anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: You need jQuery version 1.7+, @user2087078. Check my updated answer with live demo.

Answer (score 0):

use `live` for dynamically generated html..

```
$("#option1").live("click",function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Deprecated as of 1.7 - [http://api.jquery.com/live/](http://api.jquery.com/live/) use `.on()` [http://api.jquery.com/on/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)